# Sharepoint - How can I conditionally show a column OR hide a column based on selected value from another column?

Tags: sharepoint, conditional-formatting

I am having trouble to conditionally format a column to be shown as mandatory/ option or hidden based on value from another column in sharepoint.

For example:

Column 1 = Facebook/ Twitter/ Instagram

Column 2 = Yes/ No

- If user selects Facebook for Column 1, show Column 2 as Mandatory.
- If user selects Twitter for Column 1, show Column 2 as Optional.
- If user selects Instagram for Column 1, hide Column 2.

Using the example above -
I've tried the formula =if([$Column1] == 'Instagram', 'true', 'false'). However, this will show column 2 as optional if selected value for column 1 is Facebook/ Twitter.

I've also tried to configure column 2 as mandatory from column setting. However, once column 2 is mandatory, then I won't be able to insert any condition formula for column 2.

Can you please assist?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a column Mandatory/Optional using conditional formula in SharePoint.

You can only show or hide columns in a list forms using conditional formula.

Also, if you make a column as required field from column settings, you cannot add conditional formula on it. This is by design

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

You can make columns mandatory/optional by customizing the list forms using Power Apps.

For more information, check:

1. [Make a field required based on another field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Make-a-field-required-based-on-another-field/td-p/367306)
2. [How do you make a field required?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-do-you-make-a-field-required/td-p/2561)

Comment: You're welcome @EdGoh, Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.